# Display both local and UTC time

Tags: c, time, utc, localtime

I want to print both local and UTC time. The problem is that both print the same UTC time.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
  struct tm *local;
  time_t t;

  t = time(NULL);
  local = localtime(&t);
  printf("Local time and date: %s\n", asctime(local));
  local = gmtime(&t);
  printf("UTC time and date: %s\n", asctime(local));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `date` to see what your _system_ timezone is set to. (e.g. for _my_ system, I get: `Sun Nov  4 18:44:15 EST 2018` for eastern standard time). If the timezone shows up as `UTC` [as I suspect it will], you'll have to set the correct timezone with a system utility. Or, you can call `tzset` before calling `localtime`. Or, if you know the offset, you can call `gmtime` _first_ and then add/subtract `t` by the timezone offset before calling `localtime`.

Comment: The code in the question prints two different times for me. Likely the settings for whatever account you are using, or perhaps for running software in your IDE, is set to UTC as the local time zone.

Comment: @CraigEstey calling tzset() before localtime did not work. Can you tell the function that change the timezone offset?

Comment: What is your actual time zone?

Comment: Look at `timedatectl`. Do `timedatectl status` Do `timedatectl list-timezones` to get a list of timezones. Scroll down to find yours. Then, do `timedatectl set-timezone <timezone>` For me, it would be `timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York`. Note that your RTC (real-time-clock) may be set for local time instead of UTC. This can vary somewhat by your distro (e.g. fedora, ubuntu, etc.)